# Override UserManager in django

Tags: django, authentication, usermanager

How can I use a custom manager for the `auth_user` class in django?

In my django project, I'm using `auth_user` and I have a basic profile class. In every page of my site, I use some user and profile data, so every user query should join profile.

I wanted to use `select_related` in the `get_query_set()` method in a custom manager, but I cannot find any proper way to define one, or to override the existing `UserManager`. Any ideas?

Note: I don't want to override the user model. Or, to be more precise, I already overrode it in different proxy models. I want this custom manager to be used in every proxy model.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, finally found the correct answer. The cleanest way is to use a custom authentication backend.

```
# in settings:
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('accounts.backends.AuthenticationBackend',)


# in accounts/backends.py:
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class AuthenticationBackend(ModelBackend):
    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            # This is where the magic happens
            return User.objects. \
                select_related('profile'). \
                get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Answer (score 4):

This is fairly ugly but you can probably monkeypatch the User `objects` property, eg. in a middleware:

```
# manager.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import UserManager

class MyUserManager(UserManager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        qs = super(MyUserManager, self).get_query_set()
        return qs.select_related('profile')
```

---

```
# middleware.py
from django.contrib.auth.middleware import AuthenticationMiddleware
from managers import MyUserManager

class MyAuthMiddleware(AuthenticationMiddleware):
    def process_request(self, request):
        super(AuthenticationMiddleware, self).process_request(request)
        User.objects = MyUserManager()
        return None
```

Then replace the line in `settings.py`:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    # ...
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    # ...
)
```

By:

```
# settings.py
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    # ...
    'yourapp.middleware.MyAuthMiddleware',
    # ...
)
```

Note1: This code is purely theoric, never tested nor I have the time to.

Note2: I couldn't recommend using this solution from a long-term maintenability point of view.

Note3: If someone suggest something else, you should probably listen to him or her more than me.

Note4: As a probably better idea, why not trying to query for Profile, which is a model class you have total control on? You can always retrieve the user object from a profile anyway, so…

Comment: Since I cannot find any cleaner way, I'm gonna accept this answer. However, I've filled a bug report in the django BT. Wait and see. https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16379

Comment: You should really not accept this answer, because beginners could conclude that it's an acceptable approach for solving the problem you raise, while it's not.

Comment: Tried and it didn't work alas... Would of been a simple workaround for me